# Visual Studios Generating Usings

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I upgraded to Visual Studios 2015, and I noticed that the IDE likes to short cut how it generates usings.

For example:

```
namespace MyCompany.Api.Thing1
{
    using Thing2;
}
```

It generates `using Thing2` instead of `MyCompany.Api.Thing2'.

Is there a place in the settings, where I can change that to generate the entire namespace?

Comment: There are a lot of questions about this already, it is getting old and we don't need another.  Suffice to say that it only *suggests* that change, there is no reason whatsoever to let it *make* the change.  You are in control over the machine, don't let a machine control you.

Comment: Well yeah I mean I could manually insert the usings. And in the meantime, I could also use notepad++ instead of VS. And instead of driving to work, I could walk 5 hours. Anyways, I did a quick search and I couldn't find anything. Please mark as duplicate.

Comment: I did a more thorough search and I still could not find a similar question.